# CiviReport - Error when registering new Report

Tags: civireport, developer

I've generated a new report in my extension, but when I try to register it with CiviReport, I'm getting the following DB error:
Database Error Code: Field of view 'sporti62_wp4.civicrm_option_value_en_CA' underlying table doesn't have a default value, 1423
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -1
[message] => DB Error: unknown error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_option_value_en_CA (option_group_id , label , value , name , filter , is_default , weight , description , is_optgroup , is_active , component_id ) VALUES ( 41 , 'Dog Registry with Contacts' , 'dogregistry/contacts' , 'CRM_Dogregistry_Form_Report_Dog_Contact_Summary' ,  0 ,  0 ,  90 , 'Dog Registry with Contacts' ,  0 ,  1 ,  NULL )  [nativecode=1423 ** Field of view 'sporti62_wp4.civicrm_option_value_en_CA' underlying table doesn't have a default value]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_option_value_en_CA (option_group_id , label , value , name , filter , is_default , weight , description , is_optgroup , is_active , component_id ) VALUES ( 41 , 'Dog Registry with Contacts' , 'dogregistry/contacts' , 'CRM_Dogregistry_Form_Report_Dog_Contact_Summary' ,  0 ,  0 ,  90 , 'Dog Registry with Contacts' ,  0 ,  1 ,  NULL )  [nativecode=1423 ** Field of view 'sporti62_wp4.civicrm_option_value_en_CA' underlying table doesn't have a default value]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_option_value_en_CA (option_group_id , label , value , name , filter , is_default , weight , description , is_optgroup , is_active , component_id ) VALUES ( 41 , 'Dog Registry with Contacts' , 'dogregistry/contacts' , 'CRM_Dogregistry_Form_Report_Dog_Contact_Summary' ,  0 ,  0 ,  90 , 'Dog Registry with Contacts' ,  0 ,  1 ,  NULL )  [nativecode=1423 ** Field of view 'sporti62_wp4.civicrm_option_value_en_CA' underlying table doesn't have a default value]"]
```

)

I know it is likely related wp_globus plugin?  I do have two languages on my site - english and french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, again solved my own problem after doing more research.  This apparently is a known issue with mySql and MariaDB where strict mode seems to be default.  Adding sql_mode=""
to your /etc/my.cnf file will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this! This helped us out this morning.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone happening upon this - the proposed solution is not correct. CiviCRM should function with STRICT mode enabled, which is enabled to ensure data integrity - turning it off is just ignoring the unlaying problem. If you come across an error like this one it should be reported so it can be fixed.